# Inject application properties from an external source such as API with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have yml files such as

1. application.yml

configuration:
  sqs:
    user: 
    pass:

2. application-dev.yml

configuration:
  sqs:
    user: 
    pass:

I would like to call a custom method to get user and password from different sources such as API call to a webservice. Please advice if we have a way to do it.

I have researched and see a way to override getter and setter for POJO and implement our methods inside methods.

I'm looking for if any better way for it

Thanks,s

Answer (score 0):

You can just write your own authentication provider like you can se here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider

Comment: This is not for Authentication

Answer (score 0):

You should give it a try to [Spring Cloud Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/). You can define your properties per environment and you can store them in different sources ( e.g: git, any JDBC compatible database, Subversion, Hashicorp Vault, Credhub and local filesystems )

Comment: Thanks. Currently we need to communicate to AWS for a complex process to pull some data. And we can't use Spring Cloud config.